# Javascript Dynamic height not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm a newbie when it comes to JavaScript coding. I'm trying to customize the advanced slider plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-slider-jquery-xml-slider/132618) with a dynamic height for every slide. I want to fire an event every time the user views another slide. See my demo page: http://josephespana.com/hughesnet/videos-v2.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var thisHeight = $('.active').height() + 100;

    //Adjusts height on first load
    $('#responsive-slider').animate({ height: (thisHeight + 'px') }, 500, 'swing');

    //Adjusts height while clicking through slides
    $('#responsive-slider a').click(function() {

        var thisHeight = $('.active').height() + 100;

        //Modern browsers
        $('#responsive-slider').animate( { height: (thisHeight + 'px') }, 500, 'swing');

    });
});
```

This works for all of the modern browsers, but to my surprise this does not work on IE8. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What advanced slider plugin?

Comment: Sorry forgot to explain that part. I'm using this plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-slider-jquery-xml-slider/132618.

Unfortunately the plugin doesn't have options for slides dynamic height so I'm trying to add it myself.

Comment: You might consider a more full-featured plugin like [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/container-resize.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but Cycle2 doesn't seem to have all of the features I need. Btw, thanks for the quick responses. :)